# htaccess rule conflict with another rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ product.php?ref=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /category.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

The values sent with variable sub conflicts with values from ref

```
product.php?ref=$1 [L]
category.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Rules re incorrect since 1st and 3rd rule will match the same URI pattern `^([^/]*)$` and whatever rule is at top will take precedence.

Comment: ok how can i solve this :\

Comment: You need to chose a different URL pattern for /category.php?sub=` handler and a different one for `/product.php?ref=`

Comment: could you give me an example, please ? thanks for your time

Comment: For ex: `/home` will match both patterns and rule on top will take precedence and it will internally send to `/produce.php?ref=home` It is better your clearly write your requirements also.

Comment: sorry i can't understand it .. i'm new to htaccess :\

Comment: i have 2 pages i want to control with htaccess the first category and i send to it variable name sub to pass the value and the other page is product which i pass value through ref vaiable

Comment: You need to have distinct pattern for those 2 pages e.g. make products page `/p/product-id` then category page can remain `/some-category` Let me know if this is fine with you?

Comment: ok that's okay i can make product like                                   /i/test and keep category as it .. but sorry can you give me the rules thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little bit of change following code should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 

# don't do anything for a valid file or directory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Product handler /i/test
RewriteRule ^i/([^/]+)/?$ /product.php?ref=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# PHP handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]

# category handler
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /category.php?sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mywebsite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: I had a typo in very first rule, made a correction, try it again.

Comment: What URL did you try?

Comment: this is work   RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^i/([^/]*)$ /product.php?ref=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /category.php?sub=$1 [L] but style on product page don't work

Comment: Yes that should work. Regarding style, js etc make sure to always use absolute paths for those files. i.e. paths starting with `http://` or `/`

Answer (score 2):

My advice for any kind of rewrite rules that intend some form of semantic URLs, that is:

```
/home
```

instead of

```
index.php?page=home
```

Make one rule that captures all URLs, like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?__url=$1 [QSA]
```

Then have handler.php figure out what you want to do.

You know your categories and products, so if the URL is `/[product|category]` then handle it.

Comment: i have 2 pages i want to control with htaccess the first category and i send to it variable name sub to pass the value and the other page is product which i pass value through ref vaiable